# regexp fails for utf8 character matching, even when using re.UNICODE

Tags: regex, python-2.7

If i match a utf-8 string, i dont get a match

```
>>> print re.search('^([\w\.]+),[\s]+', 'Baştovoi, A', re.UNICODE)
None
```

but if a replace the utf8 char with an ascii equivalent, it works.

```
>>> print re.search('^([\w\.]+),[\s]+', 'Bastovoi, A', re.UNICODE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f21501ca648>
```

Why is this happening? 
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unicode string:

```
>>> print re.search(u'^([\w\.]+),[\s]+', u'Baştovoi, A', re.UNICODE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7417f60>
```

Comment: It works on my simplified testcase, but 'Baştovoi, A' is actually a variable in my code. unicode(s) raises "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5"

Comment: @Quamis, Instead of hard-coded unicode literal, you can use `decode` method to convert a string to unicode object: `'Baştovoi, A'.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: @Quamis, The point is that you should pass unicode object as the second argument instead of string object.